# How to build n-gram models and evaluate new sequence likelihood in nltk python ?

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

So the task seems obvious I checked [nltk ngram](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/model/ngram.html) and [nltk probability module](http://www.nltk.org/howto/probability.html) but couldn't find a simple example or a clear documentation  of building an ngram model than estimate the probability of a new incoming sequence, say of words, using any probabilistic distribution from nltk.probability . Help please !